# Create a Database Diagram based on MS SSAS Data Source View in a printable format

Tags: visual-studio, ssas

in Visual Studio (2017 SSDT), if I open my MS SSAS cube, in the "Cube Structure" tab, under "Data Source View" I see all the tables/views that are used with all the relationships.

Since there are a lot of tables (with a lot of attributes) it is not possible to see all of them on the screen.

Is it somehow possible to export this Data Source View from Visual Studio or any other tool in a printable version (into jpg, pdf,... any format), to see all tables and attributes, and relationships?

Thank you.

BR, Tadej